# How to use Garcia's WebDriverManager with Spring's Request?

Tags: java, spring, webdriver, webdrivermanager-java

Currently I use ThreadLocal to keep WebDriver, but want to use Spring's Request instead with combination of Garcia's WebDriverManager. Any success with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use dedicated scope from cucumber-spring.